# How can I set a control behind another control in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm New in Android World 
I have an activity which preview images by imageview and the image view take a fill parent and fill all the screen, I want when i click the image view show for example a seekbar on the top of the image without reducing the image size . 
note the seek bar already invisible and i show it correctly 
but i want it show on the image view itself without reduce the image height.
thanks

Comment: Use Relative Layout.. ex: http://android.programmerguru.com/android-relativelayout-example/

Comment: Another example you can find, when you create Android project in eclipse, in the wizard you can find Create Activity step, just select FullscreenActivity and finish the project, refer the generated code.

Comment: Special thanks to all